# Parsing String value into JsonElement gives MalformedJsonException

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to create a JsonElement using the following code:

```
String updateUrl = myurl + "/new_url";
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement updateUrlJsonElement = parser.parse(updateUrl);
```

Gives me

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected EOF at line 1 column 6
at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:65)
at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:45)
```

Any ideas, how can i create a JSONElement with just a String value.

Comment: share the json also ?

Comment: @JunedAhsan I think `myurl + "/new_url"` is the JSON. It's meant to be a JSON string.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Then why exception is a surprise ;)

Comment: Yes: updateUrl is the JSON. Actually i want to input a JSON Element to a library and best way i found out to do so was to create a JSON from String and then parse it to a JSONElement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the JSON format](http://json.org/), a JSON string is enclosed in double quotes. You'll have to enclose your `String` value in double quotes.

```
String updateUrl = "\"" + myurl + "/new_url" + "\"";
```

Note that you can also just create a `JsonPrimitive`, a subtype of `JsonElement`, with the given `String`.

```
new JsonPrimitive(updateUrl); // without the quotes
```